# Incorrect Figures output from foreach / counter

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the code below to count correctly but it doesn't give me the right results - am I missing something obvious?

The information is grabbed via XML (all working okay) - currently the foreach loop goes through two times. If the variable revrat is set at 3,2 or 1, then it adds to the $negrat counter (which it currently does) - however even if revrat is 3,2 or 1, it is still added to the $posrat counter despite the if statement indicating that it should only be 4 or 5 to add to that counter.

I've tried with and without the speech marks - comes to the same answer.

Thanks for looking!

```
foreach($xml->FEEDBACK as $value)
{
    $feedbackitem = $value->PRODUCTCODE;
    if ($feedbackitem == $skuvalue): 
        $i2++;
        $revrat = 3;        

        if($revrat = "1" or $revrat = "2" or $revrat = "3") :
            $negrat++;
        endif;
        if($revrat = "4" or $revrat = "5"):
            $posrat++;
        endif;  
    endif;  
}
```

Comment: Look up the difference between `$a = 1` and `$a == 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single = sets the value, == tests if the value is equal. So your if statement:

```
if($revrat = "4" or $revrat = "5")
```

is just testing that it can set $revrat equal to 4 or 5. Both return true so the if statement is true. If you change it to:

```
if($revrat == "4" or $revrat == "5")
```

then it will check to see if the current value of $revrat is equal to 4 or 5 and return the response you're looking for.

Comment: Technically, the `=` operator returns the value that is being set; so `if ($x = 0)` will return false.

Answer (score 0):

your If operators contain a `=` (assign) rather than `==` (equal to) change your code to look like this:

```
foreach($xml->FEEDBACK as $value)
                        {
                            $feedbackitem = $value->PRODUCTCODE;
                            if ($feedbackitem == $skuvalue): 
                                $i2++;
                                $revrat = 3;        

                                if($revrat == "1" or $revrat == "2" or $revrat == "3") :
                                    $negrat++;
                                endif;
                                if($revrat == "4" or $revrat == "5"):
                                    $posrat++;
                                endif;  
                            endif;  
                        }
```